# Trying to copy a char* to another char*

Tags: c++, string, memory, char, allocation

I have a problem that my code

```
char* strdup(const char* s)
{
    int n = 0;

    for(; *s != 0; s++)
    {
        n++;
    }

    char* p = new char[n+1];

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        p[i] = s[i];
    }
    p[n] = 0;

    return p;
}

int main()
{
    const char* p = "testing";

    char* p_copy = strdup(p);

    std::cout << p << '\n' << p_copy << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

doesn't work as intended.

I want to write a function which takes in const char* and copies it to a new allocated char memory. When it is done it should return a pointer to the char.

Now when I try it out my output is simply:

```
testing
```

thanks for any help in advance

Comment: why don't you use `strcpy` or `memcpy` like functions.

Comment: Copying `char*a` to `char*b` is trivial: `b = a`. The code here is trying to copy the **data** that the pointer points to. That distinction is not trivial; ignoring it always leads to trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not incrementing `s` before you start copying it to `p`. I notice that in your first `for` loop you increment `s` until it points at a null, and then later use that pointer value to start your string copy. No wonder you are getting a null string.

Comment: oh my god thank you! I totally forgot that the increment assigns a new value for my `s` now it makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

Here:

> ```
> for(; *s != 0; s++)
> ```

You increment `s`. So it no longer points to the beginning of the input string. It points to the null terminator of the string. Then, here:

> ```
> for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
> {
>     p[i] = s[i];
> ```

You try to copy `n` characters starting from the null terminator, and you end up reading past the end of the array which has undefined behaviour.

Solution: Make a copy of `s` for counting the characters:

```
const char* s2 = s;
for(; *s2 != 0; s2++)
```

Even better, you could refactor the length counting part into a reusable function called `strlen`.